# POS Thermal Printing on Localhost IIS in ASP.Net Error- No Printer are Installed

Tags: asp.net, iis, printing, pos

I had created POS Web Application in asp.net C#. Slient Thermal Printing works well when run on .Net IIS Express.

If i set it on Windows 7 IIS 6.1 printing not working. 
IIS-->Application Pool-->Identity=LocalSystem. Also given access of local printer to IIS_Users still not printing..Error - No Printer are Installed

```
PaperSize psize = new PaperSize("Custom", 100, 200);
System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings ps = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
ps.PrintToFile = true;              
System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument pd = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController printControl = new System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController();
pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "RONGTA RP80 Printer";
pd.PrintController = printControl;
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize;
pd.PrinterSettings = ps;
pd.Print();
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: What type of printer is it? Is it a network printer or a locally connected printer? Make sure that the printer exists. Make sure a default printer has been installed.try to repair or reinstall the printer driver. use the IIS application pool identity to the network service.

Comment: if possible use iis 7.5, not iis 6.

Comment: Hi, Printer Type- Thermal Printer auto cutter, Locally connected to laptop. Printer has been set as default printer.. It was print receipt properly with auto cut when run on .Net IIS express. If run on windows IIS it gives exception No Printer are Installed

Comment: did you try to set the application pool identity to the network service or the custom user administrator? and please refer this link for more detail: [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/0a92fcw1(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Tried application pool-->Network Service. but didn't work.

Comment: does your application or site ask for any permission to access the printer at the time of printing?